# Image on website not showing on on Chrome

Tags: html, css, wordpress, google-chrome, web

Not sure what's going on, but one of the images on our site is not showing up only on Chrome.

The website is http://www.divorceattorneyinlongisland.com/
If you look at the site in Firefox or Safari, you'll see a wide image with logos right below the main slider.

But the same image doesn't show up on Chrome.

Not sure why this is happening, but any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it work if you set `display: block` on that image?

Comment: Try adding the width:100%; for that image container class. Btw that page is doing something really heavy. I suggest you to optimize your slider code, it nearly reloads the image part every second. I didnt even have time to change the style on the page cause of the reload interval.

Comment: The answer of crazymatt is correct, but I'd strongly recommend to recheck the whole code, it's doing something strange and keeps reloading images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking through your code if you comment out the `position: relative` which is running on your awards-strip.jpg image the image will show correctly on Chrome.

```
.mk-image-shortcode img {
    position: relative; /*comment me out or over write me*/
}
```

Hope that helps